# How to fill the logarithmic spiral with color

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

I have written a snippet to draw a logarithmic spiral, now the curves drawing is done, but for the color filling part, I'm not familiar with how to fill it (part between the two curves, and part between the curve and outer circle border). How to finish the color filling part? Is `fill_between` more suitable here?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
b = 0.2
a = 2

theta = np.linspace(0, np.pi * 3.0, 1000, endpoint=True)


r = exp(b * theta) * a

theta0 = np.linspace(0, np.pi * 4.0, 1000, endpoint=True)
r0 = [r[-1]] * len(theta0)


theta2 = np.linspace(np.pi, np.pi * 4.0, 1000, endpoint=True)
r2 = exp(b * theta) * a

ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')

ax.set_rmax(r[-1])
ax.fill(theta0, r0, c='blue')
ax.plot(theta, r)

ax.plot(theta2, r2)
ax.fill(theta2, r2, 'red')


theta3 = np.linspace(0, np.pi * 2.0, 1000, endpoint=True)
r3 = [a] * len(theta3)

plt.box(on=None)
ax.fill(theta3, r3, c='black')

ax.grid(False)
plt.show()
```

What I have got now:
[image]

Comment: It looks like the spiral runs in the wrong direction, too (the border line is horizontally flipped from your goal). Fixing that first might make it easier to reason about the rest of the problem.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks! The reason I make it a reverse direction is that I only find the formula for such direction, I think we can use a flip function to revert it to the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to create a close line for the fill command, putting together the different pieces:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

b = 0.2
a = 2

theta1 = np.linspace(0, np.pi * 3.0, 1000, endpoint=True)
r1 = np.exp(b * theta1) * a
theta2 = np.linspace(np.pi, np.pi * 4.0, 1000, endpoint=True)
r2 = np.exp(b * theta1) * a
theta3 = np.linspace(np.pi, 0, 1000)
r3 = r1[-1] * np.ones_like(theta3)
theta4 = np.linspace(np.pi, 2 * np.pi, 1000)
r4 = a * np.ones_like(theta4)
theta5 = np.linspace(np.pi, 2*np.pi, 1000)
r5 = r1[-1] * np.ones_like(theta5)
theta6 = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 1000)
r6 = a * np.ones_like(theta6)

# put together the different pieces
theta_final_red = np.concatenate([theta1, theta3, np.flip(theta2), theta4])
radius_red = np.concatenate([r1, r3, np.flip(r2), r4])
theta_final_blue = np.concatenate([theta1, theta5, np.flip(theta2), theta6])
radius_blue = np.concatenate([r1, r5, np.flip(r2), r6])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.set_rmax(r1[-1])

ax.fill(theta_final_red, radius_red, "r")
ax.fill(theta_final_blue, radius_blue, "b")
ax.plot(theta1, r1)
ax.plot(theta2, r2)

# black inner circle
theta3 = np.linspace(0, np.pi * 2.0, 1000, endpoint=True)
r3 = [a] * len(theta3)
ax.fill(theta3, r3, c='black')
ax.axis(False)
ax.grid(False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It's so cool!  But The blue color can be seen on the outermost part of the red part(Looks like a thin line), I hope this place can be removed

Comment: Seems we also need a mirror flip to make the direction counterclockwise， but I can't find such an API.

Comment: updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! Any suggestion on the `mirror flip`  like APIs?